# Combine these specific javascript functions

Tags: javascript, function, refactoring

I have these two separate javascript functions that perform the same task using either numbers or white space. I'm not all that familiar with functions so my question is how would one combine the following two into one?

```
function padnum(string, length)
{
    while (string.length < length) {
        string += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    }
    return string;
}

function ws(string, length)
{    
    while (string.length < length) {
       string += " ";
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: When `padnum` will be called and when `ws` will be called?

Comment: combine them into what?

Comment: Give an example of result you want to have

Answer (score 2):

Consider how the two functions you want to combine differ. Then "factor out" those differences to create a generic function. In your case the single difference is in the padding rule to use--either a space, or a random digit.

In theory you could add some kind of boolean flag or "type" parameter, and then do an `if` or `switch` inside your function to choose the desired behavior. That is a horrible design. Your function will grow and grow as you add more options. This is the approach taken by one answer, which unfortunately is the currently accepted one.

Instead, since in this case the differences are in **behavior**, represent those  different behaviors as functions to be called back. That's what functions are for--to represent behaviors! Your function would then have the signature `pad(string, length, padFunc)`. This is a better approach, and is the one taken by some other answers. However, IMHO at least one of those answers is a bit poorly designed in the way it overloads the meaning of `padFunc` to be either a function or a string.

A modern, functional approach would be to write a higher-order function which creates a padding function based on a rule, called `fn` in the below:

```
function padder(fn) {
  return function(string, length) {
    while (string.length < length) string += fn(string, length);
  };
}
```

(I'm passing `string` and `length` to the padding function, just in case it wants to use them for anything. Or it could ignore them.)

Now to make a padder which pads with blanks:

```
const blankPadder = padder(() => ' ');
```

Or to make a padder which pads with random numbers:

```
const randomPadder = padder(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
```

A die-hard functional programmer might write these as:

```
const K      = k => () => k;
const random = n => () => Math.floor(Math.random() * n);

const blankPadder  = padder(K(' '));
const randomPadder = padder(random(10));
```

Here `K` is the traditional name for the [K combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus), the function which returns a function which always returns the same value.

Comment: The environment I'm using is giving me an ambiguous syntax error when trying to use either of the 'const'. Can you suggest another way to use it please?

Comment: @MHaase Try using `var` instead, but if your environment doesn't like `const`, it might also not like arrow functions, so you might have to rewrite them as `function() { return ' '; }` etc.

Answer (score -1):

The only difference is the concatenated value. You can create a function to concatenate a return value.

```js
function pad(string, length, fn) {
  while (string.length < length) {
    string += typeof fn === 'string' ? fn : fn();
  }
  return string;
}

const padnum = (str, len) => pad(str, len, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
const ws     = (str, len) => pad(str, len, " ");

console.log(padnum('00', 5));
console.log(ws('Hello', 8));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score -4):

You can pass a parameter to function to return value which meets condition

```js
function padnum(string, len, type) {
  while (string.length < len) {
    string += type === "randomPad" ? Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) : " ";
  }
  return string;
}

var len = 5;

var spaces = 2;

var res = padnum(padnum("abc", len, "randomPad"), len + spaces);

console.log(res, res.length);
```

Comment: @MHaase The approach at Answer no longer returns expected results?